# How do you change the PowerShell version run from the Power User Menu? (WinX)

Tags: powershell, context-menu

After upgrading to PowerShell 7+ the version of PowerShell that runs from the Power User Menu (Win+X) is still the 5.1 PowerShell. Is there a setting to change this to the new version?

I understand you do not want to remove the old version because of other integrations etc. I don't want to uninstall PS 5.1 I just want the quick way I often open PS to use the new version.

[image: Power User Menu]

Comment: “Is there a setting to change this to the new version?” No; However, on Windows 11, you can set the default terminal application to Windows Terminal and a by product of that action allows you to setup a profile for PowerShell Core instead of PowerShell 5.1

Comment: That is controlled by the OS, WInPS is part of the OS< hence what you have. Create your own shortcut and pin it to the taskbar and add a hotkey shortcut to start it.  Skipping the need to futz with WinX. Now, know this you can modify the WinX menu (there are plenty of step-by-step docs online to show you how), but IMHO, that is way too much effort, vs the taskbar/desktop shortcut route. Using the Windows terminal route is just another shortcut. WinTerm allows more than just PS, so still a prudent option, but it too would not appear via WinX, but will be on your start menu.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not on 11 and likely won't be for another few years. I like that suggestion as a possibility in the future though.

Comment: @postanote usually the "just do it some other way is" more patronizing than helpful, your comment was not an exception. If I wanted to do it another way I wouldn't have asked this question. Thank you for attempting though.